# Flutter passing icon parameter as constructor

Tags: android, flutter, parameters, widget, icons

This is the page of my setting menu widget page or code

```
class Setting extends StatelessWidget {
  Setting(this.title);

  String title;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
       ),
     body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      setttingWidget(Icons.favorite),
     ],
   )
  );
 }
}
```

And this is settingWidget page or code :

```
class setttingWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  setttingWidget(IconData next);

  var next;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(next),
          Text("Network Setting",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want set the icon image from the setting Widget, so use icon data but no icon is appear in app, there the code also show no error at all.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Do it like this,

```
class Setting extends StatelessWidget {

final title;
  Setting({this.title});

  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
       ),
     body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      setttingWidget(Icons.favorite),
     ],
   )
  ));
 }
}
```

Setting widget-

```
class setttingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final IconData next;
  setttingWidget({this.next});

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(next),
          Text("Network Setting",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You have to use `final` keyword because stateless widgets are immutable, that means they can not change their state.

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the point. That's is really helpfull.

Comment: Glad it worked, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try my code below :

```
class Setting extends StatelessWidget {
  Setting(this.title);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
       ),
     body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      setttingWidget(Icons.favorite),
     ],
   )
  );
 }
}

class setttingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData next;
  
  setttingWidget(this.next);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(next),
          Text("Network Setting",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note :**  If a widget is stateless, one or more of its instance fields must be final. So,

Change this :

```
var next;
```

to

```
final IconData next;
```

**Output :**

[image]